# Is it possible with Jssor to place a pause button on the slider and play?

Tags: jquery, jssor

is it possible with Jssor to place a pause button on the slider and play?

Attached image of how I want my slider to be

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hi, please put the source code of your effort. Thanks

Comment: I am using the Jssor plugin for wordpress

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can add toggle play button as static element.

```
<div id="jssor_1" ...>
    <div data-u="slides">
        <div><!-- slide 1 --></div>
        <div><!-- slide 2 --></div>
    </div>
    <div id="togglePlayButton">
        <!-- static content here -->
    </div>
</div>
```

On the button click call

```
jssor_slider_instantce.$Play();
```

or

```
jssor_slider_instantce.$Pause();
```

https://www.jssor.com/development/slider-with-fixed-static-element.html

Comment: Is it possible to combine the plugin with the code?

Comment: Although you can add manual script code, but with the plugin, you can't add `div` element in the slider.